# No package 'fribidi' found

Tags: linux, package, perl-module, cpan

I try to install module **Text::Bidi** with `cpan` but I get the following message:

> Package fribidi was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fribidi.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>        No package 'fribidi' found
>
> at Makefile.PL line 13.
>
> It seems that fribidi is missing.
>
> fribidi should be installed prior to the installation of this module.

I try to:

```
yum install fribidi

Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security

 Setting up Install Process No package fribidi available. Error:

 Nothing to do
```

I search for this issue, but don't find nothing.

**OS: **Oracle Linux 6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle only have a package for this for version 4 of their distro. It looks like you'll need to build it from source. See [GNU FriBidi](http://fribidi.org).

Comment: I've tried but I still have a same problem .   ($PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig)